# Google Apps migration API batch doesn't send/insert emails

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gwt, google-email-migration

I'm trying to send emails using Google Apps Migration API v.1, however I fail to send them and Code does not throw any exception or error.
Here is my code:

```
    MailItemService   mailItemService = new MailItemService("exampleCo-exampleApp-1");
    mailItemService.setUserCredentials("user","password");

    MailItemEntry entry = new MailItemEntry();
    Rfc822MediaSource mediaSource = new Rfc822MediaSource(mail.getInputStream().toString());
    entry.setMediaSource(mediaSource);
    entry.addMailProperty(MailItemProperty.STARRED);
    entry.addMailProperty(MailItemProperty.UNREAD);
    entry.addLabel(new Label("pruebas"));
    MailItemFeed feed = new MailItemFeed();
    for (int i = 0; i < mailItems.size(); i++) {
         BatchUtils.setBatchId(mailItems.get(i), Integer.toString(i));
         feed.getEntries().add(mailItems.get(i));
   }
   mailItemService.batch("domain", "destinationUser", feed);
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you define what you mean by "send"? It's against the APIs ToS to use it for anything other than migration of old mail to a mailbox (e.g. performing regular new message mailbox inserts is not allowed). If you're trying to send the mailbox new mail, use [SMTP and/or IMAP](https://developers.google.com/gmail/oauth_overview).

Jay